# Call jQuery var in php function

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Is it possible ?

Here is example :

```
  <script>
    var id=$(this).val();
    $('#region').append(< ? php get_region(#####) ?>); 
  </script>
```

I need to call "var id" instead of #####

Comment: uh.... what? any way you could be more clear?

Comment: You need to use AJAX to call a PHP script to run this function.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the value to PHP? It's a little unclear. If you are just use an ajax request and POST.

Comment: Also you have to understand that the PHP code block would have executed before your JavaScript even starts on the client side.

Comment: OK, ajax post do job for now. Thx

Comment: *"I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."*

Answer (score 0):

in my understanding, php is loaded first on the server, and then goes to client side ex. javascript (which includes jquery). You can obtain a copy of php variable in client side very easily, by either embedding a hidden variable. ex.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" />
```

or

```
<a title="<?php echo $a; ?>" />
```

You can also do this,

```
<script language ="javascript"> var global_variable="<?php echo $a; ?>"; </script>
```

However, php function can not refer to javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the id of "this" is going to be before the page is rendered on the browser (and THEN the javascript code will be run), then you can do the following:

```
<script>
    <?php $id = $whatever_the_id_is; ?>
    $('#region').append(<?php get_region($id); ?>); 
</script>
```

If you don't know what the id will be of "this" before rendering the page, then you need to use ajax to run the get_region() function server side and return the string you're looking for.